# How to prevent AndroidStudio from formatting custom line breaks?

Tags: android, code-formatting

**Problem**
AndroidStudio formats custom line breaks.
Version: Dolphin | 2021.3.1

**What I've tried**
I tried to disable this function like below:
AndroidStudio> Preferences> Editor> Code Style> Java> Wrapping and braces> Keep when reformatting > unchecked "Line breaks"

But the problem remained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

**Solution**

Step 1: Uncheck "Line breaks" in AndroidStudio> Settings> Editor> Code Style> Java> Wrapping and braces> Keep when reformatting>

Step 2: Uncheck "Reformat again to remove custom line breaks" in AndroidStudio> Settings> Editor> Code Style> Formatter>